# Jaxb: attribute fixed value in annotated class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I generate XML schema (XSD) from Java classes with JAXB. I wonder how to specify the value of a static attribute by using annotations.

For example I define an attribute like this

```
@XmlAttribute(name="tooltip")
private static final String TOOLTIP = "A string";
```

And I want to get in my XSD

```
<attribute name="tooltip" type="string" fixed="A string">
```

So, how can I force the generation of static attributes in XSD with JAXB?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of JAXB 2.2, there isn't standard [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) metadata that can add to your model to cause the `fixed` attribute to appear in the generated XML Schema.  The schema generation errs on the side of being too permissive rather than too restrictive.  This means you can't do the following:

- Mark a fixed value for an attribute
- Mark a maxOccurs other than 1 or unbounded
- etc.